# LDAP schema: extend one branch with another branch

Tags: oracle, ldap, oid, directory-server

I'm using OUD 12c and I would like tho achieve something like the following.
Suppose I have two branches in my LDAP:

```
ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
ou=users_special,dc=example,dc=com
```

Is it possible to set on LDAP side that ou=users_special extends the ou=users branch?
So every search in the ou=users branch will automatically look even at the ou=users_special.

Note: no, I can't search for the users in the base dn.
Thanks

EDIT:

I try to re-explain because it seems the goal was not clear.
I have two users with these two DN:

```
uid=user0,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
uid=user1,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
```

I need that both of these ldapsearches work.

```
ldapsearch -h localhost -p 1389 -b "ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" (uid=user0)
ldapsearch -h localhost -p 1389 -b "ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" (uid=user1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not schema -- schema defines what attributes exist on an object. You're talking about a [referral](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/oid/administer/oid_knowledgeref_refer.htm).

The following LDIF creates an OU with a referral:

```
dn: ou=users_special,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: add
objectclass: top
objectclass: extensibleObject
objectclass: referral
ou: users_special
ref: ldap://LDAPHOST:PORT/ou=users_special,dc=example,dc=com??sub?(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)
```

I created a user with uid "specialuser01" in ou=users_special,dc=example,dc=com. A query set to follow referrals at base ou=users,dc=example,dc=com for uid=specialuser01 returns the account that is in the

```
***Searching...
ldap_search_s(ld, "ou=users,dc=example,dc=com", 2, "uid=specialuser01", attrList,  0, &msg)
Getting 1 entries:
Dn: uid=specialuser01,ou=users_special,dc=example,dc=com
cn: special User01; 
objectClass (4): top; person; organizationalPerson; inetOrgPerson; 
uid: specialuser01;
```

However a search that *doesn't* follow referrals will return 0 entries.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But since I didn't know how to do the link maybe it was possible to set something up in the schema or in the config. Anyway, as per the question, I'm using OUD 12c which is the new version of OID.

Comment: Well, I would like to extend the searches, I don't want to redirect all the searches to ou=users_special. My goal is that every search that client does over ou=users, the server returns also searches on ou=users_speclal. So probably - if I'm not understanding wrong - refferrals are not helpful

Comment: That is what this accomplishes. In my test directory, I have three 'regular' users in ou=users and one 'special' user in ou=users_special. A subtree search that follows referrals using the base ou=users with a filter (uid=*) returns all four users. If I search at ou=users for (uid=RegularlUser01), I get that record from ou=users. If I search for uid=SpecialUser01, I get the record from ou=users_special. The 'gotcha' is that clients need to *follow* referrals. IIRC, you can use the OUD Directory Proxy and have *it* chase referrals so clients don't require any special search settings.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for accomplish this through a proxy, since I have no control to the client

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oud/OUDIG/setting_up_proxy.htm#OUDIG00005 -- the installation bit is the same as setting up OUD, but you pick a different type of server. Define the backend LDAP servers and build network groups to control who can do what. My recollection is that you configure each network groups to follow referrals automatically & there's nothing on the link to the back-end to accomplish that. To avoid inconsistent network group creation, I had a script that took an app name & list of IP addresses then created a network group based on our standard settings.